# catkin build fails after upgrading ROS distro

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04, thus I reinstalled ROS Melodic after uninstalling Kinetic.
roscore and some other basic ROS packages work fine, however when I try to build my workspace with `catkin build` following error message appears:

```
CMake Error at /home/user1/projects/catkin_ws/src/custom_package/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

The package and workspace was working fine before (on another melodic machine). I tested to create a new empty workspace with `catkin init` but `catkin build` still throws the same error message.

I also did source `/opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`. My cmake version is 3.10.2

Anyone knows how to solve this? Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355253/catkin-build-fails-after-upgrading-ros-distro/) by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2020-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, somehow I could build a new empty workspace with `catkin build` after I reinstalled the `ros-melodic-catkin` package.
In the old workspace, doing `catkin clean` then retrying to build then also worked.

---

Originally posted by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) with karma: 146 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1